# How to have ASP.NET Core DI to get the dependency resolved by Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, simple-injector, asp-net-core-spa-services

In an ASP.NET Core web api project I'm using Simple Injector and JwtBearer tokens. I have defined my custom token Event handler class and have bound it to ASP.NET Core mechanism as below:

```
private void ConfigureSecurity(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var encodedKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config[Konstants.SecretKey]);
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(encodedKey);

    services.AddTransient<TokenAuthenticationEvents>();
    var authentication = services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });

    authentication.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.EventsType = typeof(TokenAuthenticationEvents);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = _config[Konstants.AudienceKey],
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = _config[Konstants.AuthorityKey],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = key,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
        };
    });
}
```

Here is my class Token Events:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;
    private readonly IUserManager _users;


    public TokenAuthenticationEvents(ILogger log)
    {
        _log = log ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(log));
        _users = null;
    }

    public override Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        //Some Custom Logic that requires IUserManager 

        return base.TokenValidated(context);
    }
}
```

I'm using Simple Injector as my DI container

```
services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
{
    options
        .AddAspNetCore()
        .AddControllerActivation()
        .AddViewComponentActivation()
        .AddPageModelActivation()
        .AddTagHelperActivation();
    });
    services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
    services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
```

`IUserManager` along with all its dependencies is registered in Simple Injector. if I try to pass in `IUserManager` in `TokenAuthenticationEvents` an exception is raised that ASP.NET Core could not resolve `IUserManager`. So my question is

*How do I tell ASP.NET Core DI to get the `IUserManager` resolved from Simple Injector?*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as Simple Injector *cross wires* ASP.NET Core components, you can do the same the other way around, although you will have to do this manually. For instance:

```
services.AddScoped<IUserManager>(c => container.GetInstance<IUserManager>());
```

Comment: can the calls for Objects that ASPNET Core cannot find in its DI be automatically directed to Simple Injector. There might be many other dependencies. That means to make ASPNET Core find them, we have to add that line for each of them.

Comment: Due to limitations in .NET Core's DI container, this can't be done automatically. This shouldn't be a problem, though, as the number of Simple Injector-controlled services that you need to inject in .NET Core provided components should be minimal. If you need this a lot, there's something wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't solve your initial problem, but I did notice you are mixing the old Simple Injector ASP.NET Core configuration model with the new. You currently have the following code:

```cs
    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
    {
        options
            .AddAspNetCore()
                .AddControllerActivation()
                .AddViewComponentActivation()
                .AddPageModelActivation()
                .AddTagHelperActivation();
        });

        services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
        services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
```

The calls to `EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring` and `UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping`, however, are the old API and will be removed in a future release. Those features are automatically enabled when you call `.AddAspNetCore()`. So you can reduce your configuration to the following:

```cs
    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
    {
        options
            .AddAspNetCore()
                .AddControllerActivation()
                .AddViewComponentActivation()
                .AddPageModelActivation()
                .AddTagHelperActivation();
        });
```

Comment: just for info, do we need to have AddViewComponentActivation() and AddTagHelperActivation() in a pure WebAPI based project? I believe that's related to the typical web app not web api?

Comment: You are correct. In a web API project, you don't need those extension methods. As a matter of fact, you likely don't need tge integration package that contains those methods. That package also depends on many ASP.NET Packages you don't need. The packages are setup as a pay-for-play union model abd that's why there are separate methods.